# Every method on empty array looking for prime numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a pretty hard time understanding what is going on in this FreeCodeCamp exercise code:

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
  let primeNumbers = new Array;

  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    if (primeNumbers.every(prime => i % prime !== 0)) {
      primeNumbers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return primeNumbers.reduce((sum, prime) => sum + prime);
}

console.log(sumPrimes(10));
```

Why does the every method here even work when the array (primeNumbers) is empty. And secondly how does the condition work with a parameter prime when there is nothing in the array from where does the function get the value for the parameter prime from?

Comment: Similar to mathematics, every statement about attributes of the elements of the empty set is true. In other words, `[].every(_ => false) === true`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What about the parameter prime? How can i % prime be even a condition if prime itself does not exist because the array is empty?

Comment: Think about how often the function will be called, for an empty array, then consider whether your perceived problem is actually one.

Comment: It will be called one time then the i variable will be increased by one and it will be called again and so on until i becomes bigger than the variable num. Am I right?

Comment: No (at least if we both talk about the function being passed to `Array.prototype.every`) - if there is no element in the array, the condition, which should hold for every element, will never be called. The function is being passed in, but there is no element to perform the check for. You can test this, e.g. by `[].every(_ => { throw new Error("this doesn't happen."); })`

Comment: I am sorry I can't follow you.. When I console log the primeNumbers variable I see that only the numbers passing the condition get pushed to the empty array?

Comment: It should be "passing the condition for every element in the array `primeNumbers`" - and yes, exactly that is happening. However, for the first number, `2`, `primeNumbers` is empty, and therefore the condition `prime => i % prime !== 0` needs to hold for no element, as there is none. It will therefore never be called, and the question what the parameter `prime` will be makes no sense, as it would be "what will the argument be for the non-existant call".

Comment: I think I got it :) Thank you so much for your help dude appreciate it!